# Calculating Factorial of Expression using Recursion (Prolog)

Tags: recursion, prolog

So I have a question about Prolog recursion. I have to create a recursive rule **factfunc(F,X,Y,N)** that finds **((2X+3Y)^(N))!**. I have to implement this rule using two other rules that i **already implemented** (tested them and they both function correctly. The two rules I must use are **expfunc(Y,X,N)** which calculates **Y = X^N** recursively and **compfunc(R,X,Y,N)** which calculates **R = (2X+3Y)^(N)**. In my factfunc implementation I know I don't have to directly use expfunc, since my compfunc rule already uses it. That being said, here is my attempt at the factfunc(F,X,Y,N) rule:

```
factfunc(F,X,Y,N) :-
    compfunc(F1,X,Y,N),
    N1 is N-1,
    factfunc(F1,X,Y,N1),
    F is N*F1.
```

I stepped through my code numerous times 
and it makes logical sense to me, however, I keep receiving an output of "no" when I test the rule. I was hoping someone could at least nudge me in the right direction of how I can write this rule.

As always, thank you for any help :)

Comment: So how exactly the function `((2x+3y)^n)!` can be represented recursively? Can you write it mathematically? What is the base case and what is the step here?  It can be broken down to subfunctions (which you have partially done already), which can be represented recursively, but not the whole function.

Comment: The base case of this rule is when n = 0 and it can be represented mathematically as F = n*(n-1)!, where n = (2X + 3Y)^N

Comment: You are totally mixing things up here. The `n` you are talking about now is totally not the `N` from the question. In the question `N` is denoting the power. In your comment it is a parameter to factorial function. Factorial function CAN be calculated recursively, but it is only a part of your function, and this is exactly what I said.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand how it should work mathematically and understand how to define it recursively, however, i'm still having a bit of trouble understanding how to go about fixing my code. Ill just keep trying. :)

Comment: In recursion, you need a termination case. You don't have one in your code. `N1 is N-1` continues to decrease `N`, but to what end?